# What is the relation between Pyspark's Estimator and RandomForestClassifier

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I'm currently working with **pyspark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier** and pyspark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator. I can obviously use a RandomForestClassifier as the CrossValidation's "estimator" param. However RandomForestClassifier doesn't seem to be inheriting from **pyspark.ml.base.Estimator**.

On the other side, looking to the source code of RandomForestClassifier (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/ml/classification.html#RandomForestClassifier), I can't figure out where RandomForestClassifier implements it's fit method (which in my opinion should be happening even if it were inheriting from Estimator, so when you call RandomForestClassifier.fit() you get the RandomForestClassifier implementation).

So how is it possible to use RandomForestClassfier as a "estimator" in CrossValidator? What is the relation between these two classes and where is the RandomForestClassifier fit method implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the source you linked, `RandomForestClassifier` inherits from `_JavaProbabilisticClassifier`:

```
class RandomForestClassifier(_JavaProbabilisticClassifier, # ...
```

which inherits from `ProbabilisticClassifier`:

```
class _JavaProbabilisticClassifier(ProbabilisticClassifier, _JavaClassifier, # ...
```

and from `Classifier`

```
class ProbabilisticClassifier(Classifier, # ...
```

and from `Predictor`:

```
class Classifier(Predictor, # ...
```

and finally, `Estimator`:

```
class Predictor(Estimator, # ...
```

---

For your second question, the `fit` method was defined in `JavaEstimator` [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/ml/wrapper.html):

```
class JavaEstimator(JavaParams, Estimator, metaclass=ABCMeta):

    def _fit_java(self, dataset):     
        self._transfer_params_to_java()
        return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)

    def _fit(self, dataset):
        java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
        model = self._create_model(java_model)
        return self._copyValues(model)
```

where `self._java_obj.fit` calls the `fit` method of the Java/Scala classifier object.

The `JavaPredictor` is inherited by `_JavaClassifier`, which is inherited by `_JavaProbabilisticClassifier`

```
class _JavaClassifier(Classifier, JavaPredictor, # ...
```

---

Note that `Estimator.fit` calls `_fit`. See [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/ml/base.html#Estimator.fit) for its definition.